# How to handle child click event in Expandablelistview in Android?

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I'm creating expandable list view in Android. I have add three textview in relative layout and two buttons in horizontal linear layout means this two buttons are added in one row, so how can I fire click event on those two buttons?

And I want to call another activity on button click in expandable list view. But I did not find any idea how to click on child in `ExpandableListView`.

Here is my XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="2dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView_Projectdetails"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
        android:paddingLeft="10sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textOne"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView_Projectdetails"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
        android:paddingLeft="10sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTwo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textOne"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
        android:paddingLeft="10sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" >
    </TextView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlAYOUT"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textTwo"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_EditedTask"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shape_two"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="3sp"
            android:paddingTop="3sp"
            android:text="ASSIGN TASK"
            android:focusable="false"      
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonViewTask"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shape_one"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="3sp"
            android:paddingTop="3sp"
            android:text="VIEW TASK"
            android:focusable="false"      
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

List_Group xml file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp" 
    android:background="#000000">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textColor="#f9f93d" />

</LinearLayout>
```

here is my `ExpandableListAdapter` class -

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;
    Context context;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
            HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    public ExpandableListAdapter
    (My_Project my_Project, List createGroupList,
            int listGroup, String[] strings, int[] is, List createChildList,
            int childItem, String[] strings2, int[] is2)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) 
    {
        //this.get(groupPosition).getChildren().get(childPosition);
        String strchildPosition = this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
        System.out.println("Child Position  =" + strchildPosition);
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView_Projectdetails);
        TextView txtOneListChild = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textOne);
        TextView txtTwoListChild = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textTwo);



        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        txtOneListChild.setText(childText);
        txtTwoListChild.setText(childText);




        Button btnAssgnTask = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_EditedTask);
        btnAssgnTask.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Intent i=new Intent(context,Assign_Task.class);
                //StartElementListener()

            }
        });


        Button btnViewTask = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonViewTask);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Here is my Activity code -

```
public class My_Project extends ExpandableListActivity 
{


    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener()
        {
            @Override
                public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                        int groupPosition, long id) 
                {
                    return false;
                }
            });


            expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            dtrProjectNAmeSize.length + " Expanded",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });


            expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            dtrProjectNAmeSize.length + " Collapsed",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });


            expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                     int cp = (int) mAdapter.getChildId(groupPosition, childPosition);
                     if(cp == 3)
                     {
                         switch (cp)
                         {
                                case 3:



                                break;

                         }
                     }


                    return false;

                }
            });



            mAdapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
                        this,
                        groupData,
                        R.layout.list_group,
                        new String[] { Project_Name },
                        new int[] {R.id.lblListHeader },
                        childData,
                        R.layout.child_item,
                        new String[] { Project_Date_Created , Project_End_Date , Project_Is_Active},
                        new int[] { R.id.TextView_Projectdetails , R.id.textOne , R.id.textTwo }
                        );

                expListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);  

    }



    }
```

Answer (score 12):

You can set setOnChildClickListener of chid of the expandable listview then can you go to the other activity according to the value of the array list that are use for create expandable listview.

```
            menuExpandableListView
                    .setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onChildClick(
                                ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                                long id) {
                            GoCategory(mainMenusList.get(groupPosition)
                                    .getPagesList().get(childPosition));
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
```

Or you can do this

```
@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Page page =(Page) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_list_layout, null);
    Button button1=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
     button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                Your code here....


        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: @Ad Abdul Gafur, But i have to add two buttons in one row on child list view side by side so how to fire click event on that buttons.

Comment: @Ad Abdul Gafur, can you give me a code of GoCategory function.

Comment: @Ad Abdul Gafur,I i have allready tried this code but i don't know how to call another activity from getChildView in ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter class.How can i call another activity.

Comment: @Ad Abdul Gafur, Please give me a solution.

Comment: the first snippet worked for me right off the bat.  UPVOTED!

Comment: @MdAbdulGafur Abdul Gafur when I tried to do so I am accessing parent view by parent.getchildat(group position) and it gives me null pointer exception any way to prevent this

Answer (score -1):

What are you trying to do here-

```
expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                     int cp = (int) mAdapter.getChildId(groupPosition, childPosition);
                     if(cp == 3)
                     {
                         switch (cp)
                         {
                                case 3:



                                break;

                         }
                     }


                    return false;

                }
            });
```

This listener is using for child item click, call `startActivity(intent)` in this part of code.