# Display multiple clickables in Custom child of listview

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I have been stuck on this for 1 to 2 days. I need help. I want to add a custom child in a listview and a child (row) must contain multiple clickable buttons or views.

I want listview just like one given below:

[image: Listview with custom Child]

My GUI:

[image: Click here to see my Interface]

Comment: Get help from this and try http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html and http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24242694/how-to-handle-child-click-event-in-expandablelistview-in-android http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener.html

Comment: what you did till the date ? if yes post here

Comment: Can i display the two rows in a single line or row?